# Targeting a specific column in a DataRow

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to perform the C# equivalent of `Select * where [columnname] = [value]`. I began with a `foreach` loop to iterate through the table row by row, however I had forgotten that one cannot access a column via `row.column["<colname>"]`.

How do I achieve this objective? Most of the examples I have seen target one specific row with the intention of casting it's value to a string, however my task is to move all entries with a value of `DateTime == < DateTime.Today` to an archived table.

Can I continue with the following code? Or am I approaching this in the wrong manner?

```
void archiveDates()
{
   foreach (DataRow row in workingupdates.storageTable.Rows)
   {
       //target DateTime column here                         
   }
}
```

Comment: DataTable has a Select method. Check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Field` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) that is strongly typed and also supports nullable types. You have an overload for the index, name or the `DataColumn`(among others):

```
foreach (DataRow row in workingupdates.storageTable.Rows)
{
   DateTime dt = row.Field<DateTime>("columnname");          
}
```

If you instead want to find all rows where the date column has a specific value you can use `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
var matchingDataRows = workingupdates.storageTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<DateTime>("columnname") == dateTimeVariable);
```

Now you can simply enumerate this query:

```
foreach (DataRow row in matchingDataRows)
{
   // ...                      
}
```

Or create a collection like

- a `DataRow[]` with `matchingDataRows.ToArray()` or
- a `List<DataRow>` with `matchingDataRows.ToList()`
- a new `DataTable` with `matchingDataRows.CopyToDataTable()`

Note that you have to add `System.Linq;` to the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks, I think the linq expression works. I don't have the option of compiling it just yet, but there appear to be no errors. 

OOI, does `AsEnumerable` refer to an "object in selectable bits"?

Comment: @Wolfish: `AsEnumerable` is just an extension method that returns `IEnumerable<DataRow>` so similar to `workingupdates.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()`. Note that a [`DataRowCollection`](http://tinyurl.com/otfz3f9) is older than LINQ and generics, so it doesn't implement `ICollection<T>` but just `ICollection` and can only return objects. That's the reason why you need to cast it to `DataRow`. A `foreach` makes this also but implicitly: `foreach (DataRow row in workingupdates.storageTable.Rows){}` tells the compiler that the objects returned from `DataTable.Rows` are `DataRow`.